# socat with EXEC:script spawns 5 processes/sec

Tags: linux, socat

I'm using socat to run a script that cat's the output of a file.
The script looks like this:

```
while true
  do
    echo hello
    sleep 1
  done
```

The socat command looks like this:

`socat -v -d -d -d EXEC:"bash script" TCP4-listen:4444,reuseaddr,fork`

While this works well, I noticed that my pid numbers were really high.
This is caused by socat.
Notice time stamps:

```
20:45:42 0 $ echo $$
9693

21:02:36 0 $ echo $$
14767
```

So in ~17 minutes, 5074 processes have been created.
Thats about 5 every second.

- Why does socat spawn so many processes?
- Is there a better way to run this command? Better socat command and/or better script?

I don't think high pid's affects the system, but it seems a bit overkill for such a simple scheme.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `bash` script is spawning a new process (`/usr/bin/sleep`) every second. That's probably your culprit.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, should not this increase the pid by just one every second? I get about 5 new pid's every second.

Comment: There are generally other things going on in the background on your system. On my "idle" system, I see PIDs increasing around 15 every 5 seconds. You could use something like [bpftrace](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace) or the [audit subsystem](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8485/monitoring-system-calls-in-a-reliable-and-secure-way) to track all the calls to things like fork or exec to figure out what's going on.